# how to filter array and set max amount of duplicate PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new in stackoverflow and it's my first question.

here's my problem.

let's say I have array like below :

`$array =[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5];`

I'd like to filter array above so that the duplicate value (1 & 3) can be move to another array max = three time.

what I expect is :

```
$FilteredArray = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5];
```

note : 1 & 3 only move three time.

thanks in advance.

**update** : sorry, I forgot to mention that my array is contain an object. 
please refer to below :

```
>   $array = [  
>     {
>       "id": 3175,
>       "shape_id": 307,
>       "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257591914493",
>       "shape_pt_lon": "107.60664492839",
>       "shape_pt_sequence": 2,
>       "shape_dist_travel": "",
>       "jalur": "146-147",
>       "distance": 0.16133102419521
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 3180,
>       "shape_id": 308,
>       "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257591914493",
>       "shape_pt_lon": "107.60664492839",
>       "shape_pt_sequence": 2,
>       "shape_dist_travel": "",
>       "jalur": "147-146",
>       "distance": 0.16133102419521
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 3176,
>       "shape_id": 307,
>       "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257911430218",
>       "shape_pt_lon": "107.6069118082",
>       "shape_pt_sequence": 3,
>       "shape_dist_travel": "",
>       "jalur": "146-147",
>       "distance": 0.16415806438464
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 3179,
>       "shape_id": 308,
>       "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257911430218",
>       "shape_pt_lon": "107.6069118082",
>       "shape_pt_sequence": 1,
>       "shape_dist_travel": "",
>       "jalur": "147-146",
>       "distance": 0.16415806438464
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 3174,
>       "shape_id": 307,
>       "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257312336896",
>       "shape_pt_lon": "107.60638207192",
>       "shape_pt_sequence": 1,
>       "shape_dist_travel": "",
>       "jalur": "146-147",
>       "distance": 0.16421114665333
>     } ]
```

the number 1,1,1 in array values above is the shape_id.

sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should make an attempt and post what you've tried.

Comment: hi Jordan S,

well noted. I will do that next time ~

Answer (score 1):

This should help -

```
$array =[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5];
// Get unique values
$unique = array_unique($array);
// array with all values as keys to calculate occurrence
$value_count = array_combine($unique, array_fill(0, count($unique), 0));

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    // Check if occurrence reached the limit & do process
    if(isset($value_count[$value]) && $value_count[$value] >= 3) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    } else {
        // increment count
        $value_count[$value] += 1;
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

**Output**

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [6]=>
  int(3)
  [7]=>
  int(3)
  [9]=>
  int(4)
  [10]=>
  int(5)
}
```

[Working code](https://eval.in/709858)

Comment: hi Sougate,,

Thank you for your respond. it works great.

unfortunately, i forgot to mention that my array is an object. it looks like below :

$array = [ { "no":1, "name" : "josh", "value":1 }, {"no":1, "name" : "george", "value":2 }, {"no":1, "name" : "giant", "value":3 }, {"no":1, "name" : "doraemon", "value":4 }   ]

so, when i implemented your code, it doesn't work.. any sugestion ??

Comment: It is a `JSON` string. `json_decode($string, true)` should give you the array.

Comment: I tried it. but, as i mention above. when i implement it in my code, it only copy the "no" to new array. what i expected is that the whole object is copied, namely, the no, name, and value. but, I really appreciate your fast respond so much. thanks.. @Sougate Bose

Comment: You have to implement it that way then.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do this using `array_count_values`

```
$array = array("1","1","1","1", "1","2","2","2","2","3","3");
$newarray = [];

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
    $value = $array[$i];
    $counts = array_count_values($newarray);
    if($counts[$array[$i]]<3){
    $newarray[] = $array[$i];
    }

}
print_r($newarray);
```

Will output

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 [5] => 2 [6] => 3 [7] => 3 )
```